# How to change Phonegap InAppBrowser's button colors

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, inappbrowser

Have searched high and low and cannot find an answer to this one. Simply, is it possible to customize the "Done" button color as well as the arrow colors in the Phonegap InAppBrowser? They seem to default to blue on iOS7. Would like to make them white. Thanks.

Comment: Everything that you can customize about the InAppBrowser should be written in the [API guide].[1] Customizing the button colors is not supported, although you could achieve this by hacking the InAppBrowser plugin.
 [1]: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser

Answer (score 4):

Please note that, if you update the line of code to change the color of the Done button inside of the **setCloseButtontitle()** function and do not pass in the **closebuttoncaption** parameter in your JS call

Example without **setCloseButtontitle()**

```
ref = window.open(link, '_blank', 'location=no');
```

Example with **setCloseButtontitle()**

```
ref     = window.open(link, '_blank', 'location=no,closebuttoncaption=Close Window');
```

then the button color will not change, so I would recommend adding the line of code to change the button's color after the following function code:

```
if (browserOptions.closebuttoncaption != nil) {
                    [self.inAppBrowserViewController  setCloseButtonTitle:browserOptions.closebuttoncaption];
 }
 //add this here so it will change the color of the button regardless of the browserOptions.closebuttoncaption being passed
 self.inAppBrowserViewController.closeButton.tintColor =[UIColor whiteColor];
```

Comment: This worked for me. No amount of changing tintColor in setCloseButtonTitle() did anything for me.

Comment: I second that this worked while the others did not.  It does not however, change the color of the back and forward arrows.  Looks like its time to learn some Objective C

Answer (score 2):

```
Project Navigator>>CordovaLib>>Classes>> Commands>>CDVInAppBrowser.m
```

find `self.closeButton` and put below after `self.closeButton` button initialization

```
self.closeButton.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Answer (score 2):

@Ved's answer isn't accurate anymore.

Now in that same file you need to find the line in `setCloseButtontitle()`:

```
self.closeButton.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:60.0 / 255.0 green:136.0 / 255.0 blue:230.0 / 255.0 alpha:1];
```

and change it to:

```
self.closeButton.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

for arrow buttons also add these lines:

*

> self.inAppBrowserViewController.backButton.tintColor =[UIColor
>   whiteColor]; 
>   self.inAppBrowserViewController.forwardButton.tintColor=[UIColor
>   whiteColor];

*